# Burn tag [clean-string]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [clean-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clean-string) tag had exactly two questions, now zero. It is hardly a useful category.

Comment: If you've already removed it from all questions, there is nothing left to do - tags without questions are removed automatically after a day.

Comment: Two! That's more than about half the tags used on SO!

Comment: Thanks for the information. It seems worthwhile to me to record my actions here. Don't understand the unexplained downvote.

Answer (score 3):

The tag has been automatically removed from the system as you removed the tag from all its questions. Proof: [Click here to reach a 404](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/clean-string/info)

The tag is now burninated!